# How do I configure an AWS Network Load Balancer to preserve client IP addresses using Terraform?

Tags: terraform, aws-nlb

The AWS console allows an NLB target group to be configured to preserve client IP addresses:

[image: Preserve client IP addresses]

However, this setting doesn't appear to be available in Terraform's load balancer target group:
https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/resources/lb_target_group

**How can I enable this option through Terraform, or is it not supported?**

*Preserve client IP addresses* is an option within the Attributes section of a load balancer target group. Other options there are *Proxy protocol v2*, *Stickiness*, *Connection termination on deregistration* and *Deregistration delay*. The Terraform LB target group includes `proxy_protocol_v2`, `stickiness`  and `deregistration_delay`, but not the other two options (as far as I can see).

[image: EC2 Target Group properties]

Comment: Where exactly is this screenshot coming from?

Comment: This is from the AWS console _Load Balancers (EC2 feature)_, select _Target Groups_, choose an NLB target group, then on the _Group details_ tab there is an _Attributes_ section including this _Preserve client IP address_ option. The screenshot shows the checkbox which appears on clicking _Edit_.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As of v3.35.0 of the AWS provider, it is now [possible](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/resources/lb_target_group#preserve_client_ip).

Answer (score 1):

Looks like it's not possible to configure via Terraform at the moment, but at least it doesn't get overwritten if you set it manually.